# Trouble styling active state in css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a an active state on me site [Click Here](http://bodyworksforme.com/?/shop/view-copy/relax) which i am able to pick up in firebug. i have created an active state for the following tab `Relax and unwind` which i have scripted the following way

```
<li {if segment_3 == "relax"} class="active"{/if}><a href="{path='shop/view/relax'}">relax &amp; unwind</a></li>
```

I trying to style this tab in css but it doesn't seem to work.

```
.sub-nav-products li .active{
    color: #fff;
       }
```

Comment: the correct selector is: li.active

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the space between `li` and `.active` and add `a` after:

```
.sub-nav-products li.active a {
    color: #fff;
}
```

This example sets style to anchor inside list element which has class "active".

Comment: Yup done that, as you can see in firebug, but is still hasn't changed color

Comment: @NewBoy Alright. Check the update. Now it will work perfectly.

Comment: I wrote another answer more or less the same but referencing a w3c spec, but +1 to acknowledge this answer was here first.

Comment: Thanks richard for your contribution

Answer (score 1):

The space between `li` and `.active` is a [descendant combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#descendant-combinators). So your selector:

```
.sub-nav-products li .active
```

...represents a `class="active"` element being the descendant of an `<li>` element which is in turn a descendant of a `class="sub-nav-products"` element.

Using that rule, your HTML would have to look something like this:

```
<ul class="sub-nav-products">
    <li>
        <span class="active"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Since you're targeting a `<li>` element with the `class="active"` attribute, you don't want to use a combinator between `li` and `.active`, but instead a [sequence of simple selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selector-syntax):

> A sequence of simple selectors is a chain of simple selectors that are not separated by a combinator.

... which means you should remove the space between `li` and `.active` in your selector:

```
.sub-nav-products li.active
```

But wait! There's more: the web browser probably has a default rule for anchor elements `<a>`, and you're trying to style text in an anchor element:

```
<ul class="sub-nav-products">
    <li class="active">
        <a href="#">Example</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

You need to write a rule with higher [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity) targeting that `<a>` element directly, so in the end we're looking at:

```
.sub-nav-products li.active a
```